# Word that describes a society that glorifies war?

Tags: word-choice

For exmaple

"Before  societies, people often went to war without know the true horrors"

Comment: Your example sentence is filled with errors!

Comment: What do you mean "Before societies, people...."? Only the question title saves you.

Comment: -1 from me because you showed no research.  Because your example sentence is not English

Comment: You had me at *exmaple*.

Comment: Is there such a thing as a society that doesn't glorify war?

Comment: @hotlicks Mongolia? Scandinavia? Sure they got it all out of their systems, but nowadays they're pretty calm.

Comment: In many societies spanning history, warfare was widespread and constant, but also low-intensity, and fought by citizen soldiers rather than professional armies. So be careful what you assume about knowledge, and about glorification, and about horrors— what horrors the Lelantine War saw pale when compared to Cannae, and in turn Borodino, or the Somme, or Hiroshima.

Answer (score 4):

***[Bellicose](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bellicose)*** also comes to mind. (M-W)

> favoring or inclined to start quarrels or wars

"A Bellicose Society"
["One Million Mercenaries" by John McCormack](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=kHN-AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=%22bellicose%20society%22&source=bl&ots=Q1ZsQyAtAI&sig=eLxfe2EldE6Iga21mLa_Et2lWb8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MttVVfnvMI-8ugTvqIG4Cw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22bellicose%20society%22&f=false) (Google Books)

"If the Chachapoya were a bellicose society..." 
[The Routledge Handbook of the Bioarchaeology of Human Conflict by Christopher Knüsel](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=fcJiAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA381&lpg=PA381&dq=%22bellicose%20society%22&source=bl&ots=rWoudG0lTN&sig=G4xW61wF22oIF9cDUKuSp-6E8FA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MttVVfnvMI-8ugTvqIG4Cw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22bellicose%20society%22&f=false) (Google Books)

"...as defended refuges in a bellicose society..."
[Tribe and Polity in Late Prehistoric Europe: Demography, Production, and ... edited by D. Blair Gibson](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=fcJiAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA381&lpg=PA381&dq=%22bellicose%20society%22&source=bl&ots=rWoudG0lTN&sig=G4xW61wF22oIF9cDUKuSp-6E8FA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MttVVfnvMI-8ugTvqIG4Cw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22bellicose%20society%22&f=false) (Google Books)

*Pardon my style in citing references. I have zero experience as an academic researcher, and how I did it college is just a fond memory now.*

Answer (score 1):

***[Belligerent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/belligerent)*** may suggest the idea:

> - Inclined or eager to fight; hostile or aggressive. (AHD)

Comment: Thanks, can you see if you can answer my other question?

Comment: Which one sorry, I guessed it was one question.

Comment: My bad i should have linked @Josh61 http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246497/is-modernist-the-correct-word-usage-here

Comment: @Mari-LouA - fixed!!

Comment: How about a "Warrior Civilization"?

Answer (score 1):

[Militaristic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/militaristic) is probably the word you are looking for.

Check the broader concept: [Militarism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Militarism)